# ink! tutorial: contracts-node fails to compile

Tags: ink

sorry if this is not the right forum, but here goes:

`cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.10.0 --force --locked`

This fails with the latest rustup toolchain:

### active toolchain

```
nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.61.0-nightly (3b348d932 2022-02-19)
```

The reason is:

```
error[E0658]: trait bounds other than `Sized` on const fn parameters are unstable
   --> /Users/jonathan/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/crossbeam-epoch-0.9.8/src/atomic.rs:314:6
    |
314 | impl<T: ?Sized + Pointable> Atomic<T> {
    |      ^
...
346 |     pub const fn null() -> Atomic<T> {
    |     -------------------------------- function declared as const here
    |
    = note: see issue #93706 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93706> for more information
    = help: add `#![feature(const_fn_trait_bound)]` to the crate attributes to enable
```

How can I get past this? Seems an update is necessary
Thx!

Comment: You stable toolchain version would be of interest here. The part you posted will be compiled using your stable compiler as it is not part of the runtime. Unless you aren't overriding it manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rustup default nightly`, and then rerun. It's accessing nightly features. I can confirm that it builds using cargo 1.61.0-nightly (65c8266 2022-03-09) on linux.